# AWS SNS: How to query the analytics API

Tags: push-notification, analytics, amazon-sns

Recently start using AWS SNS to send push notifications to both platforms (Android, and IOS), however I need to show the notification analytics on third party CRM but, I can not find an easy way to query specific notification between two dates specially with so much unreadable documentation.

Is there any way to achieve that?